# calling the jQuery ajax method multiple times on click event

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi
so basically i would like to achieve this:
when a user clicks  an onclick event (here's the html):

```
<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="

                $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?action=montant_global',
        success: function(html){
$('span#montant_global').html(html)
                   }
       })

"> the link  </a>
```

so im looking for a way to have this ajax method called multiple times, i could copy and paste the method multiple times inside the onclick event but im looking for a way to make it thru a .each() or something like that.
cheers

Comment: And what would the other iterations do?

Comment: i just iterate on the same function, why?, because sometimes it is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an advocate of Unobtrusive JavaScript I would put my scripts in separate file and add a class or id for the link that should run the ajax

```
$(function() {
  $(".coolAjaxLink").click(function() {
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?action=montant_global',
        success: function(html){
          $('span#montant_global').html(html)
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Change the 10 to whatever amount of times you want it called... 
If several of this links exist and with a different amount of call times I would create a "data-amount" attribute and add to the link. But it all depends if you use html5 etc etc...

Comment: are you sure this is going to loop, i ask because the i is not inside the for enclosure.

Comment: well it looks like it should work fine (i added an alert() to check if this does itereate), thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would work better by applying a class to the a tag like this.

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='trigger'> the link </a>
```

And then setting the click event like so within a script tag.

```
jQuery('a.trigger').click(function() {
    // Loop as many times as you need
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Your ajax calls here
    }
});
```

If you set it up like this it should work fine. If not, it will be down to the cache, in which case pass an extra get parameter to the file which contains the timestamp. This stops the browser loading the cached version.

Comment: And you should use something else than an anchor since it's not an anchor anymore (no real href)

Comment: @Capsule It all depends, If he wants to support non-javascript browsers he would implement a click event and return false, and still have a real link pointing somewhere for noscript ppl.

Comment: @ullmark: I don't think anyone needs to worry about that kind of compatibility anymore. It is the same as the 'Should I support IE6' argument, the percentage is so tiny it is not worth the hassle. I generally use an anchor tag for things that trigger JavaScript on click.

Comment: Using an anchor would imho still be the best. Don't forget search engines (if you want them to index stuff, depending on what you're coding). You get a pointer by default (using a span would force you to add extra css). etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajaxquery = function() {
       $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax.php?action=montant_global',
          success: function(html){
                       $('span#montant_global').html(html)
                   }
       });
};
window.setInterval(ajaxquery, 1000);
```